# ERROR: Invalid options syntax: -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, tensorflow, bazel

I am attempting to get TensorFlow working in C++ for the first time by following the instructions on => [this](https://github.com/guikarist/tensorflow-windows-build-script) page.

In PowerShell I executed

```
.\build.ps1 -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so -BuildCppAPI
```

but during the execution I get the following:

```
ERROR: Invalid options syntax: -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```

I have no idea what this means - and I don't even know what system is printing out the error or what action is failing. Below is the last part of what I see in the PowerShell window.

```
You have bazel 0.20.0 installed.
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]: n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: n
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is /arch:AVX]:


Would you like to override eigen strong inline for some C++ compilation to reduce the compilation time? [Y/n]: n
Not overriding eigen strong inline, some compilations could take more than 20 mins.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more details.
        --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
        --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
        --config=gdr            # Build with GDR support.
        --config=verbs          # Build with libverbs support.
        --config=ngraph         # Build with Intel nGraph support.
        --config=dynamic_kernels        # (Experimental) Build kernels into separate shared objects.
Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE default on features:
        --config=noaws          # Disable AWS S3 filesystem support.
        --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
        --config=nohdfs         # Disable HDFS support.
        --config=noignite       # Disable Apacha Ignite support.
        --config=nokafka        # Disable Apache Kafka support.
        --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL support.
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
c:\tf_windows_build\tensorflow-windows-build-script-master\source/.bazelrc
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Invalid options syntax: -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
INFO: Invocation ID: 8f02ecb6-9ff4-429a-841d-500d4246669f
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
c:\tf_windows_build\tensorflow-windows-build-script-master\source/.bazelrc
INFO: Invocation ID: 5fd16822-1851-41f6-ac48-fdda432096f5
```

Comment: Please take a closer look at the example on the page you referenced. That example does not tell you to run `.\build.ps1 -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so -BuildCppAPI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ERROR: Invalid options syntax: -//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
> ```
>
> I have no idea what this means

It literally means exactly what it says: you used invalid options syntax.

Turns out, you slightly misread the instructions. The command format is:

```
.\build.ps1 -BazelBuildParameters <parameter_string> [optional_parameters]
```

You took out the text "BazelBuildParameters" so you're instead doing this:

```
.\build.ps1 -<parameter_string> [optional_parameters]
```

and the computer has no idea what to do with it.

---

I reckon you wanted something like this:

```
.\build.ps1 -BazelBuildParameters //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so -BuildCppAPI
```

Comment: Spot on.... I was confused because the build.ps1 did so much stuff (taking quite a long time) all looking correct, that when the error occurred I assumed it must be some problem deep within the script rather than something as simple as the command line of the script itself.

Comment: It does point you directly to the problem though, even quoting the incorrect part of the command